# partial asynchronous functions are not detected as asynchronous

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a function which accepts both regular and asynchronous functions (not coroutines, but functions returning coroutines).

Internally it uses `asyncio.iscoroutinefunction()` [test](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html?highlight=iscoroutine#asyncio.iscoroutinefunction) to see which type of function it got.

Recently it broke down when I attempted to create a partial async function.

In this demonstration, `ptest` **is not** recognized as a couroutine function, even if it returns a coroutine, i.e. `ptest()` **is** a coroutine.

```
import asyncio
import functools

async def test(arg): pass
print(asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(test))    # True

ptest = functools.partial(test, None)
print(asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(ptest))   # False!!

print(asyncio.iscoroutine(ptest()))         # True
```

The problem cause is clear, but the solution is not.

How to dynamically create a partial async func which passes the test?

OR

How to test the func wrapped inside a [partial object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)?

Either answer would solve the problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using Python versions < 3.8 you can't make a `partial()` object pass that test, because the test requires there to be a `__code__` object attached directly to the object you pass to `inspect.iscoroutinefunction()`.

You should instead test the function object that `partial` wraps, accessible via the [`partial.func` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial.func):

```
>>> asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(ptest.func)
True
```

If you also need to test for `partial()` objects, then test against `functools.partial`:

```
def iscoroutinefunction_or_partial(object):
    while isinstance(object, functools.partial):
        object = object.func
    return inspect.iscoroutinefunction(object)
```

In Python 3.8 (and newer), the relevant code in the `inspect` module (that `asyncio.iscoroutinefunction()` delegates to) was [updated to handle `partial()` objects](https://bugs.python.org/issue33261), and you no longer have to unwrap `partial()` objects yourself. The implementation uses the same `while isinstance(..., functools.partial)` loop.

Comment: Thank you. Is the `.func` attr documented somewhere?

Comment: @VPfB: yes, the [`functools.partial()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) states it exists explicitly; the *Roughly equivalent to* code shows the attributes that are set.

Comment: The functools docs had some problems with links (in 2018), that's why I did not find the info: https://bugs.python.org/issue34748

Comment: @VPfB interesting; that bug report was opened about an hour after I wrote this answer; I think it is fair to credit your question as the reason the issue was discovered. :-)

Comment: No surprise. The bug reporter and I share the same office room.

Comment: What about [`functools.partialmethod()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod)?

Comment: @DurandA: what is your exact question? How to test a `partialmethod` object wraps a coroutine function? Then it depends on exactly what was wrapped and how you accessed the partialmethod object. If you accessed it through `ClassObj.partialmethod_name` or `instance.partialmethod_name`, and it wrapped a normal `async def` method, then descriptor binding takes place and a `partial()` object is returned. So in that case the same technique applies.

Comment: @DurandA: actually, that's not quite correct. I filed [a new bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue38364) as I discovered that this is a little more complicated. For `instance.partialmethod_name`, you can simply unwrap *first* (and you have to do this in Python 3.8) too). For `ClassObj.partialmethod_name` you *also* have to look for the `_partialmethod` attribute, follow that, and *then* follow the `.func` attribute.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by replacing all instances of `partial` with `async_partial`:

```
def async_partial(f, *args):
   async def f2(*args2):
       result = f(*args, *args2)
       if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(f):
           result = await result
       return result

   return f2
```