# Partial of a class coroutine isn't a coroutine. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

```
class Foo:
    async def foo(self, a):
        return a

async def bar(b):
    return b

asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(functools.partial(bar, 1)) # returns True, OK
asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(functools.partial(Foo().foo, 1)) # returns False, WHY???
```

I need to find a way to wrap a coroutine inside a class into partial so that the result is also a coroutine. How do I do that?

Comment: Note that your "class coroutine" doesn't have a `classmethod` decorator, so it's an ordinary method which should accept `self`. What is your actual use case?

Comment: I would like to pass such a class coroutine to aiohttp server but got the following:
aiohttp/aiohttp/worker.py", line 72, in _run
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: wsgi app should be either Application or async function returning Application, got functools.partial(<bound method Application.bla of <main.Application object at 0x7f5ebd342850>>, <Application 0x7f5ebd2a5280>)

Answer (score 9):

The why is the way the `inspect` [module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bd88ccb943c0ea672c14a87e76157fade4feae11/Lib/inspect.py#L191) checks for this.

```
def iscoroutinefunction(obj):
    """Return true if the object is a coroutine function.
    Coroutine functions are defined with "async def" syntax.
    """
    return _has_code_flag(obj, CO_COROUTINE)
```

If we look at the [definition](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d3b73f32ef7c693a6ae8c54eb0e62df3b5315caf/Lib/inspect.py#L173) for `_has_code_flag`:

```
def _has_code_flag(f, flag):
    """Return true if ``f`` is a function (or a method or functools.partial
    wrapper wrapping a function) whose code object has the given ``flag``
    set in its flags."""
    while ismethod(f):
        f = f.__func__
    f = functools._unwrap_partial(f)
    if not isfunction(f):
        return False
    return bool(f.__code__.co_flags & flag)
```

We see that it first it tries to unwrap a bound method from and get its `.func` attribute(which contains the function object) and then after that, unwrap the `partial`. Finally if the result isn't a function return `False` otherwise return the result of a flag check on the underlying function's `__code__` attribute.

The problem is that `while ismethod(f)` does nothing since at that point it is still a `partial` object. Then after it unwraps if from the `partial`, `isfunction` returns `False` because it is only a bound method there.

That is the why.
I do not know if this could be considered a bug or if it was done so by design.
The fact that the docstring for `_has_code_flag` leaves out `functools.partial` wrapped methods in its description leads me to believe it was by design.

However, you can borrow from [`functools._unwrap_partial`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bd88ccb943c0ea672c14a87e76157fade4feae11/Lib/functools.py#L421) and use their method of checking for a `coroutine` by checking the `.func` attribute.

```
def _unwrap_partial(func):
    while isinstance(func, partial):
        func = func.func
    return func
```

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52422903/12479639):

```
def iscoroutinefunction_or_partial(object):
    while isinstance(object, functools.partial):
        object = object.func
    return inspect.iscoroutinefunction(object)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67020609/partial-of-a-class-coroutine-isnt-a-coroutine-why#comment118527179_67020609), you need to create a coroutine:

```
def async_partial(async_fn, *args):
    async def wrapped():
        return await async_fn(*args)
    return wrapped

foo1 = async_partial(Foo().foo, 1)
assert inspect.iscoroutinefunction(foo1)
assert asyncio.run(foo1()) == 1
```

The difference between this and the "real" `functools.partial` is that the callable returned by the latter can be invoked multiple times.