# Best way to avoid warning about un-run coroutines that are not-yet run by cancelled tasks?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

In the following, the coroutine`runIt()` is created and provided as a parameter to `delegate(...)` - which is turned into a Task that is canceled before `runIt` executes:

```
import asyncio

async def cancelTaskTest():
    async def runIt():
        print("RunIt ran")

    async def delegate(coro):
        await coro

    task = asyncio.create_task(delegate(runIt()))
    task.cancel()

if __name__=='__main__':
    asyncio.run(cancelTaskTest())
```

Produces the unwanted warning:

```
/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:1881: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'cancelTaskTest.<locals>.runIt' was never awaited
  handle = self._ready.popleft()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I'm aware that `runIt` did not run. I don't want a warning about it - what's the best way to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest method would be to remove `()` in `runIt` and call it in `runAfterTimeout()`:

```py
import asyncio


async def cancelTaskTest():
    async def runIt():
        print("RunIt ran")

    async def delegate(asyncFunc):
        coro = asyncFunc() # <-- put () here
        await coro  

    task = asyncio.create_task(delegate(runIt))  # <-- removed () in runIt
    task.cancel()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(cancelTaskTest())
```

---

EDIT: To add parameters to `RunIt`, just create plain `lambda:`:

```py
import asyncio


async def cancelTaskTest():
    async def runIt(p1, p2):
        print(f"RunIt({p1}, {p2})")

    async def delegate(coro):
        await coro()

    task = asyncio.create_task(delegate(lambda: runIt(1, 2)))
    task.cancel()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(cancelTaskTest())
```

Comment: Yeah -- I've condered it, however, passing around coro is sometimes important. In my actual use case, I catch and log exceptions in a drop-in replacement for create_task. create_task task task a coroutine, and we should except many other method to do so also.

Comment: Plus, if your function has paramters, the lack of python's async lambda mean you also have to resort to creating parameterless async function. It doesn't even have an async version of `partial`:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52422860/partial-asynchronous-functions-are-not-detected-as-asynchronous
Also wrapping functions like this hides the function name in stack traces and debugging. Yuk!

Comment: @user48956 I cannot answer the first comment, but for the second one, just create plain `lambda:` (I've updated the answer).

Comment: Pretty good. But mysteriously, those lambdas give false when passed to  asyncio.iscouroutinefunction - which is a sad situation for decorators wanting to work for both functions and coroutine functions.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73243313/how-can-i-know-if-a-lambda-is-an-coroutine-function